# Clarification about const assertin

Tags: typescript

I have a few questions about const assertion regarding primitive types.
Assuming I have a constant number I want to use, let's say:

```
const MAX_SIZE = 10;
```

Is there any particular reason for me to use `as const` here?

```
const MAX_SIZE = 10 as const;
```

I understand that const assertion makes the type of the variable very specific and gives it `readonly` property, however whether I assert it with `const` or not I see that the type of `MAX_SIZE` is still 10;

Another thing I wanted to know is, let's say I have a new type called `Constants` that combines all the declared `const` values:

```
const Constants = {
  MAX_SIZE
};
```

Now, when I hover over `MAX_SIZE` in the Constants I see that it's of type `number`. Why is that?

If I make the `MAX_SIZE` const asserted only then the type inside Constants changes to the specific value, 10 in this case.

Lastly, if on the other hand I leave `MAX_SIZE` not const asserted and instead I make the `Constants` object `as const` the type of `MAX_SIZE` becomes 10 again, which approach is better then - using const assertion on each const value I have or making the combining object const asserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on primitives: It depends on how a variable has been declared.

- If you use `let` or `var`, TypeScript infers a primitive and no literal value.

  ```
  let MAX_SIZE = 10; // number
  ```
- If you use `const` for a primitive declaration, TypeScript tries to infer a literal value anyway as the variable cannot be reassigned. So there's usually no extra `const`-assertion required.

  ```
  const MAX_SIZE = 10; // 10
  ```

Now, when declaring an object with `const` you can still reassign its properties. The example below is totally valid code which is why it doesn't make sense to infer an object `as const` per default and why properties are set to `readonly` when using `as const`.

```
const MAX_SIZE = 10;
const constants = {
  MAX_SIZE // number
};

constants.MAX_SIZE = 11;
```

---

Also note, properties are only set to `readonly` when applying a `const`-assertion on the entire object. In the following example, `MAX_SIZE` is inferred as the literal type `10` yet is not `readonly`. This means `MAX_SIZE` can technically still be assigned a different value:

```
const MAX_SIZE = 10 as const;
const constants = {
   MAX_SIZE,
};

constants.MAX_SIZE = 11 as 10;
```

Comment: I think it would be cleared if you explicitly specified type of constants as `{MAX_SIZE: number}` because the idea is that the type of the primitive does not necessarily define the type of object.

Comment: Can you please clarify why this conversion works `constants.MAX_SIZE = 11 as 10;` ? I dont understand why it works, seems a bit weird.

Regarding the last point, I do want to create an object with immutable properties, then to achieve this I do need to make the entire object const-asserted. don't I?

Comment: Exactly; `constants.MAX_SIZE` has a literal type of `10` but we can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)  a different value (such as `11`) to the literal type of `10` as well. Please don't use that though it's only for showcase.